# BASH: while loop and read output

Tags: bash, while-loop

I would like to run `tcpdump` on ports listed from `unhide-tcp` forensic tool however currently I'm not able to validate if any ports were found with `if` statement because `while` loop lists all ports on one line: `1025 1026`

`unhide-tcp` output:

```
# unhide-tcp 
Unhide-tcp 20130526
Copyright © 2013 Yago Jesus & Patrick Gouin
License GPLv3+ : GNU GPL version 3 or later
http://www.unhide-forensics.info
Used options: 
[*]Starting TCP checking

Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1025

Found Hidden port that not appears in ss: 1026
[*]Starting UDP checking
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -f

DIR="/tmp"

while read PORT; do

# Debug msg
echo "Found Hidden port(s): ${PORT}"

    if [ ! -z ${PORT} ]; then

        echo "Found Hidden port(s): ${PORT}"
        timeout 10 tcpdump -c 50 port ${PORT} -w "${DIR}/$(date "+%Y%m%d-%T")-[${PORT}].pcap"
    fi

done <<<$(unhide-tcp | awk -F ":" '/^Found/{ print $2 }')

exit 0
```

Output:

```
# ./test.sh 
Found Hidden port(s): 1025 1026
test.sh: line 18: [: 1025: binary operator expected
```

Comment: Use `bash`, not `sh`.  `sh` doesn't support herestrings.

Comment: Do you want to pass each port separately or both at the same time?

Comment: I can't predict the number of ports this tool will find so each port will be passed separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open a new shell with `$(` command substitution, all the newline characters are changed to spaces. You can pipe the output of this command to while loop.

```
unhide-tcp | awk -F ":" '/^Found/{ print $2 }' | while read PORT; do
....
...

done
```

Comment: Hi, it seems that `if` statement doesn't work if there is no output from `unhide-tcp` command, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem by changing:

```
[ ! -x ${PORT} ]
```

to:

```
[ ! -x "$PORT" ]
```

Wrapping the variable `$PORT` in quotes means that the whole contents of the variable will be interpreted as a single argument. Without the quotes, if the variable contains spaces then each "word" will be interpreted as a separate argument.